# Преобразование в массив json строки вида:

Tags: php, javascript, json, объекты

```
&calculate=1&technicaldata={"name":["Наименование рабочей среды","Расход (кг/ч)","Температура","Рабочее давление (бар)","Допустимые потери напора (кПа)","Расчетное давление (бар)","Расчетная температура (°С)","Тепловая нагрузка (кВт)","PH Наличие хлоридов"],"hot_side":{"value":["Вода","Расход",["Вход","Выход"],"Введите данные","30","250","120","4 000","6.0"]},"cold_side":{"value":["Вода","Расход",["Вход","Выход"],"Введите данные","30","250","120","4 000","6.0"]}}
```

в php скрипте делаю так : `$technicaldata = json_decode($_POST['technicaldata']);`
Но получить доступ через $technicaldatа['name'], чтобы пройтись по массиву name foreach не выходит :( Как преобразовать строку чтобы получился нормальный массив ?

Comment: второй аргумент  true  - json_decode($_POST['technicaldata'], true)

Comment: Спасибо. сработало:)